# MPI: Report Bindings

Tags: mpi, openmpi

I am running an MPI program with specific bindings using `-rankfile` and `-hostfile` flags. How can I check if the proper bindings were made (just to be sure)? I have tried the `--report-bindings` flag. Something like:

```
mpirun --report-bindings -rankfile rank_file -hostfile host_file -n 16 ./$prog
```

However, it does not provide me any output. I am using Open MPI version 1.5.4. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It is probably that your standard error, where the `odls` framework is printing the binding information, is being redirected somewhere. It works for me with Open MPI 1.5.3:

```
$ mpiexec --report-bindings -rankfile rank_file -hostfile host_file \
          -n 4 hostname
host
[host:18314] [[35226,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[35226,1],0] to slot_list 0
[host:18314] [[35226,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[35226,1],1] to slot_list 1
[host:18314] [[35226,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[35226,1],2] to slot_list 0
[host:18314] [[35226,0],0] odls:default:fork binding child [[35226,1],3] to slot_list 1
host
host
host
```

If the library fails to report the bindings for whatever reason, you could use a simple script to check if the binding is actually taking place:

```sh
#!/bin/sh

cpuset=$(cat /proc/self/status | grep Cpus_allowed_list | awk '{print $2;}')
echo "Rank $OMPI_COMM_WORLD_RANK bound to core(s) $cpuset"
```

Simply name it `report_bindings` and run it via `mpiexec`:

```
$ mpiexec --report-bindings -rankfile rank_file -hostfile host_file \
          -n 4 report_bindings
Rank 1 bound to core(s) 8
Rank 0 bound to core(s) 0
Rank 3 bound to core(s) 8
Rank 2 bound to core(s) 0
```

Comment: Great that works. I don't know why --report-bindings flag wasn't providing information. Perhaps I have something wrong. I tend to have that problem with the program output. Sometimes it just starts to give me no information about the output but if I add another cout instruction in the code, everything works fine. I should add that it's not because of flushing because functions have been called accordingly.

Comment: Honestly I have no idea. Usually the I/O redirection of Open MPI is quite robust.